# How do I get a placeholder image to load when my image is still loading from server

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic3

I am building an application with Angular 4/ Ionic 3 that loads images that users upload from a server. I am currently using the code below but it is not working:

```
<img src="{{user.image}} || assets/images/profileimage.png" />
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I thought what it would show the placeholder image until the main image had loaded from the server. Instead it is still just blank until the main image loads. Is there something specific to Angular that I should be using?

Comment: Check it https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/img/Img/

Comment: I dont know angular or ionic. But i think your img src is wrong <img ng-src="{{user.image ||  assets/images/profileimage.png}}" /> it should be something like this

Comment: you need to set relative path. `./asstes/images/profileimage.png"`

Comment: @karthick `ng-src` is for angularjs (v1)

Comment: @suraj ok . like i said not an angular guy but src="{{user.image}} || assets/images/profileimage.png" doesnt feel right

Comment: @suraj saw you relative path comment that will work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
isImgLoaded:bool = false;
```

```ts
<img *ngIf="!isImgLoaded" src="assets/images/profileimage.png" >
<img [hidden]="!isImgLoaded" [src]="user.image" (load)="isImgLoaded = true" >
```

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell, all modern browsers should support `HTMLImageElement.complete`, so you can just use

```
<img #userImage [src]="{{user.image}}">
<img *ngIf="!userImage.complete" src="assets/images/profileimage.png">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the relative path as a string literal here .

```
<img src="{{user.image}} || ./assets/images/profileimage.png" />
```

Or Try:

```
<img [src]="user.image || './assets/images/profileimage.png'" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this YouTube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7TJuMtkpbRA) very helpful. Here is the detailed documentation for the Angular [module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-lazyload-image) which is used in the video.

**Install LazyLoadImageModule**

```
npm i ng-lazyload-image
```

**Module file**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { LazyLoadImageModule } from 'ng-lazyload-image'; // <-- import it
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, LazyLoadImageModule], // <-- and include it
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class MyAppModule {}
```

**Component file**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'image',
  template: ` <img [defaultImage]="defaultImage" [lazyLoad]="image" /> `,
})
class ImageComponent {
  defaultImage = 'https://www.placecage.com/1000/1000';
  image = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1443890923422-7819ed4101c0?fm=jpg';
}
```

Where `[defaultImage]` is a placeholder and `[lazyLoad]` is the actual image.

Answer (score -1):

Better to use this lazy load plugin. It works awesome..

Install : `npm install ng2-lazyload-image --save`

Import lazy load in  app.module.ts: `import { LazyLoadImageModule } from 'ng2-lazyload-image';`

```
 imports: [ BrowserModule, LazyLoadImageModule ],
```

in ur html replace ur img tag with this:
 `<img [defaultImage]="defaultImage" [lazyLoad]="image" [offset]="offset">`

in ur component create this vaiables :

```
defaultImage = 'https://www.placecage.com/1000/1000';
image = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1443890923422-7819ed4101c0?fm=jpg';
offset = 100;
```

For more info refer this https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-lazyload-image

If you need any help in this let me know..

Hope this helps..

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @Roopendra ..i  edited my answer

Comment: @Roopendra u can say this answer is usefull now ;)

Comment: Yeah it's better now :) Thanks ! .