# Placeholder image Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, placeholder

I have the following problem: I want to use a default image until another one is loaded via an asynchronous call. The problem is that , following this [How do I get a placeholder image to load when my image is still loading from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44580968/how-do-i-get-a-placeholder-image-to-load-when-my-image-is-still-loading-from-ser) and using this code I get both images and not one replacing the other . What should I modify ?

```
  async getData() {
     await this.gs.getMaxGifs(this.name, this.offset).subscribe((response: any) => {
       this.result.push(...response.data);
       if (this.value == 'asc') {
         this.result.sort((val1, val2) => {
           return new Date(val1.import_datetime).getTime() - new Date(val2.import_datetime).getTime()  //ASC
         })
       }
       else {
         this.result.sort((val1, val2) => {
           return new Date(val2.import_datetime).getTime() - new Date(val1.import_datetime).getTime()  //DESC
         })
       }
       this.offset += 50;
       if (this.result.length != response.pagination.total_count) {
          this.getData()
       }
     });
   }
```

.html page:

```
<ion-grid fixed>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col size="4" *ngFor="let r of result; let i = index">
      <ion-card>
        <ion-card-content>
          <img #userImage src={{r.images.downsized.url}} width="300" height="200" (click)="getDetails(i)">
          <img *ngIf="!userImage.complete" src="../../../assets/error.png">
        </ion-card-content>
        <ion-card-header *ngIf="clicked === i">
          <ion-card-title>
            title: {{r?.title}}
          </ion-card-title>
          <ion-card-subtitle>username: {{r?.username}}</ion-card-subtitle>
          <ion-card-subtitle>import date:{{r?.import_datetime}}</ion-card-subtitle>
        </ion-card-header>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Comment: It's probably better to hide the image until loaded, but if you absolutely need a placeholder image you could embed it into the codebase as a Base64 representation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the method you chose does not work in ionic.

Try this other one:

```
 <ion-card-content>

      <ng-container *ngIf="r && r?.images?.downsized?.url != null; else elseBlockErrorImg">
         <img src={{r.images.downsized.url}} width="300" height="200" (click)="getDetails(i)">
      </ng-container>

      <ng-template  #elseBlockErrorImg>
          <img src="/assets/error.png">                                
      </ng-template>

</ion-card-content>
```

I don't know how you get 'r', but if you get it asynchronously, try it changing this:

```
*ngIf="r | async; else elseBlockErrorImg">
```

Comment: Hi @juan , thanks for the answer, but it's same. Upload both images

Comment: Hi @sirss,I've just edited my answer. Try these new ways of *ngIf (I gave you 2 ways now) and good luck!  For a better help, you should show how your code gets 'r' (where it comes from, type, etc.)

Comment: Nada =( , with these new changes you no longer see the placeholder image . I have modified the post by adding how I get the data

Comment: The problem is that your conditional is checking for a URL string which you have. You are trying to show the placeholder while the image is downloading. So your conditional needs to determine if the image has been downloaded yet. This solution doesn't accomplish that.